# Jion two tables to new a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I want to join `table-a` and `table-b`

create a table-c

Please see the screenshot. My sql is postgresql

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: I am sorry i don't get it. You mean You want join table a and table b to table c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple join with a coalesce:

```
select a.ID, coalesce(a.email,b.email) as email
from tableA a
join tableB b on b.ID=a.ID
```

This assumes that the IDs exist in both tables which from your example they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COALESCE function like so:

```
select a.id,
       coalesce(a.email, b.email) email
from   table_a a, table_b b
where  a.id = b.id;
```

Here's a link to a SQL Fiddle with a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/14f12d/7

Comment: This will work, but its not a good idea to teach newcomers the join style that was superceded 20 years ago. Please look at the `join <table> on <condition>` format specified in other answer.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks @TomC :-)